# Configure the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable

Tags: react-native, shell

Going through process of setting up Android emulator for React Native
Following React documentation on website.

Instructions are as such:

Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc (if you are using zsh then ~/.zprofile or ~/.zshrc) config file:

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export

PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools

My device: 2019 Intel MacBook Pro with macOS Monterey 12.3

I tried vim.zprofile to no avail. Honestly not sure how to proceed.

when i run react-native run-android the build always fails

Answer (score 3):

First Open the respective file from terminal
using

```bash
open -a TextEdit /Users/<myname>/.bash_profile
```

*use .bashrc (if you are using zsh then ~/.zprofile or ~/.zshrc)

then when the text file opens add the respective lines to this text file.

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

hit save

CHECK IF THIS IS DONE CORRECTLY

1. Type source `$HOME/.bash_profile` for bash or `source $HOME/.zprofile` to load the config into your current shell.
2. Verify that ANDROID_SDK_ROOT has been set by running `echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and the appropriate directories have been added to your path by running ``echo $PATH```